# C arithmetic, modulus

Tags: c, math, time, codeblocks, modulus

So I have this problem I'm working on where I must determine the cost for time spent at a go kart track; they charge by the hour and if you spend 30 minutes or more for a specific hour, you are charged the full amount. Note: I am not looking for someone to just answer my hw for me, much like I don't think anyone here would do so.

I will now post my source code:

```
#include <math.h>


int main(){

float price;
int minutes;
int hours;
int total_cost;

  printf("How much does this go-kart location charge per hour?\n");
   scanf("%f", &price);

  printf("How many minutes can you spend there?\n");
   scanf("%d", &minutes);

hours= minutes/60;

total_cost=hours * price;

  printf("Your total will be $%d" ,&total_cost);



return 0;
}
```

..................................................................................

My problem is that 
. I'm not sure how to accurately calculate someones time spent, and thus the cost will be wrong. If someones spends 1.5 hours at this place, they are billed for 2 hours.And likewise if someone spends just 30 min. they are billed for 1 hour in full.

Part of me believes I am to use the modulus operator in order to round up the remainder but I'm not sure how to do so.60 minutes in an hour and I spend 30 minutes at this track,  60 % 30 would be the time spent. But this returns a remainder of 30, and spending 30 minutes would mean I pay full price for 1 hour.

Again I'm not looking for someone to answer my hw for me, it would serve me no purpose , just some general help on how to calculate a number that must always be rounded up from the half of the hour and onwards.

Thanks to anyone and everyone who helps, or just stops by.

Update; SO I added an if else statement to my problem, and it seems to be working. I'll post the updated source code below.

................................................................................

This appears to work based on some trial runs i've done, I'll have to edit the output for 2 decimal place(%.2f, I think, to make it look nicer, thanks to all of you for your help, I'm new to programming in C, and it confuses me deeply, but It's important to me to learn this, not just for some grade, so thanks for being so helpful.

Comment: Why don't you count the number of half-hours spent?

Comment: Could you try `hours= (minutes+30)/60;` ? Integer division will round the result.

Comment: @francis: this formulae breaks if we enter a multiple of 60. for 90 minutes, user should be charged 2 * price per hour. your formula takes will charge him only the price for one hour. ryt?

Comment: `(90+30)/60 = 120/60 = 2`

Comment: no no. my mistake. substituted wrong values. sorry.

Comment: you said, "they charge by the hour and if you spend 30 minutes or more for a specific hour, you are charged the full amount." What happens when somebody spends only 29 minutes? Do they get a free ride?

Comment: If you detail the expected cost for 1:00, 1:01, 1:29, 1:30, 1:31, 1:59, 2:00 hours, I suspect you will 1) have yourself a better understanding of what needs to be done and 2) so will viewers of your post.

Comment: Is that last update of your *question* actually the *answer*? Please remove it then, and add it as a proper answer. As it is, your question is no longer a question anymore and thus not a good fit for Stack Overflow's "Q&A" model. You may not be aware of this because it seems you elected to not read the [short Introductory Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) when signing on.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use floating-point types, the simplest thing to do is just round to the nearest integer:

```
int billable_hours(int minutes) {
    return (int)round(minutes / 60.);
}
```

it's worth reading up on the rounding modes to verify this will do what you need.

There's a trick to avoid worrying about rounding modes, which is to add a bias so that simply rounding *down* does what you need:

```
int billable_hours(int minutes) {
    return (int)floor(0.5 + minutes / 60.);
}
```

But that this works the same if we stick with integers (integer division discards the fractional part, effectively rounding towards zero):

```
int billable_hours(int minutes) {
    return (minutes + 30) / 60;
}
```

because any fractional hour >= 30 minutes, we force up to the next whole hour before discarding the fractional part.

---

Notes:

- these will behave differently with negative inputs. Not (hopefully) relevant here, but worth being aware of
- be aware of type promotions: the literal `60.` is a double, while `60` would be an integer. When you write `int / double`, it is promoted to `double / double` instead, so you don't have to cast. The division in the third function is still integer division, though.
- by *the simplest thing*, I mean the simplest thing to type and/or read. Computationally the third is by far the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
int extra;
hours= minutes/60;
extra = minutes % 60;
if(extra >= 30)
   hours += 1;

total_cost=hours * price;

  printf("Your total will be $%d" ,total_cost);
```

hours = minutes/60 gives the number of full hours, since hours is an integer variable. hours%60 gives you the extra minutes spent. And there is no need for an **&** before total_cost in the printf statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are rounding times to the nearest integer.  When you do integer `(modulo N)` arithmetic, one way to round things to the nearest integer is to add `N/2` to the original number of minutes (this is equivalent to the `int(x + 0.5)` problem to arithmetic `(module 1)`), so when you integer divide by N, you'll get results rounded to the nearest integer.  Try `hours_to_charge = (minutes_run + 30) / 60;` and you'll get the desired results.

### Example

So, if you have, for example 37 minutes and want to know how many hours to charge, just add 30 min to that (getting 67) and then divide by 60 (getting one hour)

But, be carefull that for times of under 30 minutes you are going to charge 0 to the cart runners.

Answer (score -1):

Just cast minutes to a float, and than round the number using ceil() and floor().  A very common way of doing this is defining a macro called ROUND to accomplish this:

```
#define ROUND(x) ((x - floor(x) >= 0.5) ? ceil(x) : floor(x))

hours = ROUND((float)minutes/(float)60);
```

This will turn your hours into billable hours, and the rest of your code will work as coded.

Comment: You realize there's a `round()` function in the same library as `ceil()` and `floor()`?

Comment: Yes @EOF there is a round().  However, round() will round .5 down to 0; so it will not work for this instance and thus under bill the user.

Comment: @EOF - I stand corrected about round moving towards zero.  However, it still does not deserve a down vote ; the answer still will work.

Comment: It's a horrifically convoluted answer to a problem that is simple and answered better in the second comment.

Comment: @EOF - possibly - however casting a float or double leaves you vulnerable to situations where the float or double can't fit into an int.  And not using round keeps your code standard C.  So while not the most efficient answer given presumptions of your input - I still don't think it's an uncommon solution.  Your just adding your personal objection.

Comment: Are you joking? *Your* answer casts integers to floats, and contains a macro with dangerous lack of parentheses. francis' comment to the original question is perfectly standard C.

Comment: Why to switch to floating numbers when this can be solved in integer space?

Comment: @Luis Colorado I agree - The int solution by francis was a much better solution to the problem.  I just quickly interjected a macro function I use sometimes to round floating numbers to int.  And after some thinking - I think a better way would be to just cast as a int after adding 0.5 to the number.

Comment: I didn't try to give a solution.  Just to ask why to solve a problem in float space when it's solvable in ints?